# Simple slideshow with navigation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

I need help making a simple slideshow to display images with a simple navigation. I do not want anything flashy - just a basic slideshow with a previous/next navigation and text that displays what number the image is out of the total images. I would also like it to fade into the next image if possible.

This is for a portfolio website and I have seen it done on many others but I cannot create a working code nor find a similar code anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Read it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/

There are plenty of other examples out there, as well, like http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/ (mentioned in the above link and pretty popular)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sexy slideshow jquery plugin my friend:

http://www.slidesjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Lightbox

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Answer (score 0):

Use the Cycle plugin (jQuery) with the pager option:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html